# Why is my Uva's 3n+1 solution is wrong?

Tags: java

I've tried every test and the output was correct,but i dont understand why it is showing "wrong answer" after my submission at UVA.Please help me to find out the problems with this code. here is my code..

```
import java.util.*;
class Main
{ `
  int counter=0;
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
      String str=sc.nextLine();
      StringTokenizer st=new  StringTokenizer(str," ");
      String a=(String)st.nextElement();
      String b=(String)st.nextElement();
      long i=Long.parseLong(a,10);
      long j=Long.parseLong(b,10);
      Main mn=new Main();
      long ans;
      if(i>j)
      {
        ans=mn.count(j,i);
      }
      else
      {
        ans=mn.count(i,j);
      }
      System.out.print(i+" "+j+" "+ans);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  long count(long m,long n)
  {
    if(m==1 && n==1)
    {
      return 0;
    }
    long input=0;
    long ans=0;
    for(long i=m;i<=n;i++)
    {
      input=i;
      while (true)
      { 
        if(input==1)
        {
          counter++;
          break;
        }
        if(input%2==0)
        {
          input=input/2;                           
          counter++;
        }
        else
        {
          input=input*3+1;
          counter++;
        }
      }
      if(counter>ans)
      {
        ans=counter;
      }
      counter=0;
    }
    return ans;
  }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a debug service.  Please find the problematic portion of your code, and show us only that portion that is related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails on the test case `1 1`.

The output should be 1, but your program gives 0.

The fix is simple:

```
if(m==1 && n==1)
{
  return 1; // instead of 0
}
```